# Wordpress diacritics insensitive search

Tags: wordpress

I'm new to wordpress and cannot find a good way how to make search on my site diacritics insensitive.

I try to accomplish it with changing search query collation to utf8_unicode_ci which does work as I need... pro problem is, I don't know how to modify search query to add the suffix `COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci'` - I guess the correct way is to create a `hook`?

I tried:

`pre_get_posts` - it allows me only to change the query object which doesn't know about collation (and I don't want to change the global one to avoid bad side effects),

`posts_request` - I don't know how to detect the correct context (only search queries from site search functionality). I saw someone claiming `posts_request` hook takes second parameter and puts in the parent $query but it returns `NULL` all the time on my installation.

Any help please?

**EDIT**

I found the required SQL statement on too simple test case and now I found out, I need to add `COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci'` after each expression separately.

Example:

`SELECT *
 FROM wp_posts
 WHERE post_title like '%some%'
  OR post_title like '%thing%';`

needs to be rewritten to:

`SELECT *
 FROM wp_posts
 WHERE post_title like '%some%' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci'
  OR post_title like '%thing%' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci';`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a pre_get_posts filter to modify the query, e.g.

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','alter_query');
function alter_query($query) {
    $query-> set('orderby' , $query->get('orderby') . ' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci' );
 }
```

**EDIT:** It appears that WordPress re-parses the orderby after the above action, removing the collate.

There is a WoordPress posts_search_orderby filter that appears to do what you want.

```
add_filter('posts_search_orderby', 'alter_query', 20, 2);
function alter_query($orderby, $query) {
    return $orderby . ' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci';
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help... the `COLLATE` statement doesn't show up in server logs... any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Just to make it clear / it gets called, it stores the collation into the order by statement, but it gets lost sometime after it...

Comment: Thank you, you helped a lot, but it doesn't solve my problem - see updated question. My fault, so sorry! I solved my problem hooking to `posts_search` and doing some `str_replace` magic.